# File System gets damaged after running the dd command

Tags: 14.04, filesystem, sd-card, dd, raspberrypi

I am trying to install the Raspbian OS on my SD card. One of the steps includes unmounting the SD card and then using the dd command.

```
sudo dd if=./2016-05-27-raspbian-jessie.img | pv | sudo dd of=/dev/sdc1
```

After running this command, I get the following error for /dev/sdc1:

```
Unable to detect file system! Possible reasons are:
 - The file system is damaged
 - The file system is unknown to GParted
 - There is no file system available (unformatted)
 - The device entry /dev/sdc1 is missing
```

How do I prevent?
Thanks!

Comment: Did you read the official documentation for installing raspbian images ? https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/linux.md  The command they list is `bs=4M` . Also, I know you're using `pv` to view progress, but maybe it's affecting the way data passes through it. Have you tried running the `dd` command alone, without `pv` ?

Comment: Yes I have tried doing it using the following command as well:
`sudo dd bs=1M if=./2016-05-27-raspbian-jessie.img of=/dev/sdb1`
I get the same error.

I also tried this on another SD card, to figure out where the problem lies. But the same problem persisted. I think it has something to do with  filesystem only.

Comment: Tried getting different  .img file?

Comment: Umm no...that could be a problem? Plus, this is the latest version and I'm not sure if I can access the older ones. I can definitely give it a try if it is not a file system problem.

Comment: It could  be. Actually,  before you go download  another img file,  let's  try checking it's  hashsum.  Hold on a few minutes

Comment: OK, so on the download page (https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/)  they give SHA sum : `64c7ed611929ea5178fbb69b5a5f29cc9cc7c157`  So in terminal run this :  `sha1sum ./2016-05-27-raspbian-jessie.img ` If the output is the same as that number on download page, then your img file is OK

Comment: No, it's not the same. I get this: `51d5e457ead8278c2626f4a544b4d046846a08df`

Comment: That means your img file is corrupted.  Get a different  one

Comment: Alright, I'll try that out and update here. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Download the same version  again and check it's  sha1sum before doing `dd`

Comment: OK, if that works out, let me know and I'll post an actual answer

Comment: No that isn't working. I have tried downloading like 3 more times. I get `51d5e457ead8278c2626f4a544b4d046846a08df` as the output every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of fiddling around, I finally solved this by skipping the step of umounting the SD card and then running the dd command.

I ran the dd command directly and it worked! I know this is not the recommended way to do this but it worked for me.